# Netlify doesn't download Parcel plugins

Tags: netlify, parceljs, web-manifest

I have a Parcel app I am trying to deploy in Netlify that uses @parcel/transform-webmanifest for the manifest file. When I attempt to deploy, I get the following error:

```
11:52:42 PM: $ npm run build
11:52:42 PM: > build
11:52:42 PM: > parcel build src/index.html
11:52:43 PM: Building...
11:52:43 PM:  Build failed.
11:52:44 PM: @parcel/core: Cannot find Parcel plugin "@parcel/transformer-webmanifest"
11:52:44 PM:   /opt/build/repo/node_modules/@parcel/config-default/index.json:20:42
11:52:44 PM:     19 |     "*.webmanifest": ["@parcel/transformer-webmanifest"],
11:52:44 PM:   > 20 | }": ["@parcel/transformer-webmanifest"],
  >    |      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Cannot find module "@parcel/transformer-webmanifest", did you mean "@parcel/transformer-babel"?
11:52:44 PM:     21 |     "*.{yaml,yml}": ["@parcel/transformer-yaml"],
11:52:44 PM:     22 |     "*.{glsl,vert,frag}": ["@parcel/transformer-glsl"],
```

adding @parcel/transform-webmanifest to my package.json (`npm install @parcel/transform-webmanifest`) produces a very similar error. What's going on here, and is there a workaround?

Comment: This looks similar to [this github issue](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/7467#issuecomment-997178605) (that was about a different plugin, but the premise is the same - parcel's "auto-install" functionality has some weirdness when running in CI). Can you clarify what happens when you run `parcel build src/index.html` locally? And do you see a reference to `@parcel/transform-webmanifest` in your `package-lock.json` (locally and on the github branch that triggers deployments)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I just get a successful build locally, and there's a webmanifest reference in my package-lock.

Comment: Ended up working after upgrading Parcel to latest version...